# Composite view models propagating change notifications

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a view model called **OperatingViewModel** that contains a reference to **LevelAListViewModel**. Each of the level view models represent the hierarchy in the underlying model. My question is, what is the best way to notify the **OperatingViewModel** of changes to any of the Level[*]ViewModels?

I've tried listening to the **PropertyChanged** event in the parent, and that works okay, but it doesn't seem very clean.

I've also tried passing the parent as a reference to the child, and then invoke a method, that then invokes it's parent on up the chain, but again, that seems bad as well.

```
class OperatingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelAListViewModel LevelACollection { get; set; }
}

class LevelAListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelAList _model;
   LevelBListViewModel LevelBListViewModel { get; set; }
}

class LevelAViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelB _model;
   LevelBListViewModel LevelBListViewModel { get; set; }
}

class LevelBListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelBList _model;
   ObservableCollection<LevelBViewModel> LevelBCollection { get; set; }
}

class LevelBViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelB _model;
   LevelCListViewModel LevelCListViewModel { get; set; }
}

class LevelCListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelCList _model;
   ObservableCollection<LevelCViewModel> LevelCCollection { get; set; }
}

class LevelCViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelC _model;
   LevelDListViewModel LevelDListViewModel { get; set; }

   DateTime StartDate
   { 
       get { return _model.StartDate } 
       set 
       { 
           _model.StartDate = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged("StartDate"); 
       } 
   }

   DateTime EndDate 
   { 
       get { return _model.EndDate } 
       set 
       { 
           _model.EndDate = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("EndDate"); 
       } 
   }
}

class LevelDListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelD _model;
   ObservableCollection<LevelDViewModel> LevelDCollection { get; set; }
}

class LevelDViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   LevelD _model;    
   int Price
   { 
       get { return _model.Price} 
       set 
       { 
           _model.Price = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged("Price"); 
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four most common ways of doing this are:

1. Listening to the child's PropertyChanged event
2. Passing a reference to a parent, and then invoking a method on the parent
3. Passing a lambda to the children which invokes a method on the parent
4. Using a loosely-coupled EventAggregator to publish a PropertyChanged event in the child, to which the parent subscribes. See Prism's EventAggregator for an example.

I would normally choose either 1 or 3, always bearing in mind the potential for both to cause memory leaks due to strong referencing. 4 is overkill if the parent actully has a reference to the child.